InvalidDimensionException: Embedding dimension 384 does not match collection dimensionality 3
Im trying to use a Semantic Search method on ChromaDB then there's got an error saying "InvalidDimensionException: Embedding dimension 384 does not match collection dimensionality 3"
Theres nothing wrong with my file, for your information the file is a .CSV and its already have an embeddings.
I try to do a Semantic Search method by using this code:

from chromadb.config import Settings
from chromadb import Client
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer

collection = client.get_collection("my_collection")

query = "What division this student?"
model = SentenceTransformer('all-MiniLM-L6-v2')
query_embedding = model.encode(\[query\])

results = collection.query(query_embeddings=query_embedding, n_results=5)

for i, result in enumerate(results\['ids'\]):
print(f"Document {i+1}: {result}")
print(f"Distance: {results\['distances'\]\[i\]}")
print(f"Title: {results\['metadatas'\]\[i\]\['title'\]}")


I expected a Semantic Search succesfully running but theres an error saying:
"InvalidDimensionException: Embedding dimension 384 does not match collection dimensionality 3"
